# Откатить изменения в Git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch

На сервере в данный момент есть ненужный коммит, его нужно удалить с сервера.

Я сделал:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

**Локально изменения откатились.** Но теперь при `push` сервер мержит те изменения которые на нем есть. Пытался сделать **Rebase** но это тоже не помогло.

Как запушить так чтобы был удален последний коммит?

Comment: Ну ваш прошлый вопрос закрыт как дубликат, не просто так же. Там есть ссылка, по которой его уже задавали и на него подробно отвечали. Возможно Вы забыли флаг -f например

Answer (score -1):

Проблему решила следующая команда:

```
git log //показывает список всех коммитов в текущей бранче и их id

git revert <id> //отменяет изменения выбранного коммита локально.
```

дальше **commit**, **push**.

Comment: ага. То есть проблема была не "как откатить коммит"? а "как мне идентифицировать коммит который хочу откатить"? Плюс мне интересно, Вы ответы на свои вопросы читаете, или просто из любви к искусству задаете? Вчера Вы спрашивали почти то же самое, и ответ получили который в результате и применили.

Comment: Когда reset --hard HEAD~1 не помог, потому что сервер автоматически мержит изменения которые уже есть в нем, и изменить это нельзя (наверное :)). После этого стал смотреть в сторону revert.